# is it possible to pass &self into another function in rust

Tags: rust

I define a pagination function in rust 1.57.0 like this:

```
impl<T> QueryFragment<Pg> for Paginated<T>
    where
        T: QueryFragment<Pg>,
{
    fn walk_ast(&self, mut out: AstPass<Pg>) -> QueryResult<()> {
        if self.is_big_table {

        }else{

        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

now I want to pass the `&self` into another function, when I define the function like this:

```
fn handle_big_table_query(&self, mut out: AstPass<Pg>){
    out.push_sql("SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () FROM ");
    if self.is_sub_query {
        out.push_sql("(");
    }
    self.query.walk_ast(out.reborrow())?;
    if self.is_sub_query {
        out.push_sql(")");
    }
    out.push_sql(" t LIMIT ");
    out.push_bind_param::<BigInt, _>(&self.per_page)?;
    out.push_sql(" OFFSET ");
    let offset = (self.page - 1) * self.per_page;
    out.push_bind_param::<BigInt, _>(&offset)?;
}
```

the visual studio code shows error that:

```
Function `handle_big_table_query` cannot have `self` parameter
```

why did this happen? is it possible to pass `&self` into the function? what should I to do pass the parameter like this in rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only methods can have `self` parameter. For free functions, either pass it as a normal parameter, or make them a method.

```rust
fn handle_big_table_query<T: QueryFragment<Pg>>(this: &Paginated<T>, mut out: AstPass<Pg>) {
    out.push_sql("SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () FROM ");
    if this.is_sub_query {
        out.push_sql("(");
    }
    this.query.walk_ast(out.reborrow())?;
    if this.is_sub_query {
        out.push_sql(")");
    }
    out.push_sql(" t LIMIT ");
    out.push_bind_param::<BigInt, _>(&this.per_page)?;
    out.push_sql(" OFFSET ");
    let offset = (this.page - 1) * this.per_page;
    out.push_bind_param::<BigInt, _>(&offset)?;
}
```